# “China is reckoned to not be prevented by…” Is this wording weird?

Tags: passive-voice

I am in doubt with regards to the sentence below

> China is reckoned **to not be prevented** by the U.S. from attacking Taiwan

How weird do native English speakers find this sentence? Are they able to understand it?

I understand the split infinitive might sound a bit odd, nevertheless I think it is right.

Comment: I [searched online](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22China+is+reckoned+to+not+be+prevented%22&sca_esv=563303096&sxsrf=AB5stBih2d-qyzEcUx8IqK-Fstg5SDdVZg%3A1694065637634&ei=5WP5ZJ_2JeOdi-gP8Z69kAs&ved=0ahUKEwjf_Lmk5peBAxXjzgIHHXFPD7IQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22China+is+reckoned+to+not+be+prevented%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiJyJDaGluYSBpcyByZWNrb25lZCB0byBub3QgYmUgcHJldmVudGVkIjIEECMYJ0jflwRQ1sADWPCRBHABeAGQAQCYAb8BoAHyBaoBAzcuMbgBA8gBAPgBAfgBAqgCCsICBxAjGOoCGCfiAwQYACBBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) and did not find the quotation. Could you please edit your question and  cite your source.

Comment: Did you create this sentence yourself? Is it your own translation? Perhaps you copied it wrongly?

Comment: I don't find it 'weird', just rather clumsy. **Reckoned not to be** is much more idiomatic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't remember having said I had a source. This is a made up sentence

Comment: Where does it say that you created this sentence? Where does it say "my"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn't know I was supposed to make clear if this was taken from the internet or was rather a sentence I made.

Comment: Questions about a passage you have read in print or online are acceptable - asking "Is this passage that I wrote correct?" is not. It's counted as proof-reading.

Answer (score 3):

Though the sentence is technically correct it is verbose, clumsy, and can be simplified.

I would've written it as:

> It is reckoned that the U.S. would not prevent China from attacking Taiwan.

Comment: Or not be able to prevent...

Comment: @TimR your solution has a different meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Yes, I know. But I'm suggesting the meaning of the original is not clear in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how to restate that passive construction **to be prevented** in active voice in a grammatical manner and with a clear predicate.

> The US is reckoned to not prevent China from attacking Taiwan.<sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Is that supposed to mean "to not be able to prevent" or "to not be preventing"?

This is ungrammatical with or without **not**:

> The US is reckoned to not prevent China from attacking Taiwan.
>
> The US is reckoned to prevent China from attacking Taiwan.

**reckoned to prevent China from attacking Taiwan** makes no sense. Here's why.

> Garlic is believed to prevent vampires from biting.
>
> Garlic is believed to not prevent vampires from biting.

It may appear that the sentences about the US and the sentences about garlic (where they are the grammatical subject of **is**) have the same structure, but on a semantic level there are two very different aspects at play.  With the vampire example, we're talking about an innate quality of garlic that *always* has (or always does not have) efficacy in preventing vampires from biting; garlic is **believed *to prevent*** or **believed not *to prevent*** and the infinitive is appropropriate; but with the US example we're not talking about anything that *always* is true or false, but about something that is true or false *at some juncture in time*, and so "reckoned" with   *infinitive* complement, whether active or passive, **to (not) prevent** or  **to (not) be prevented**, is inapplicable there *aspectually*.

The passive formulation calls for one of the following *tensed* possibilities:

> It is reckoned that China is not being prevented ...
>
> It is reckoned that China won't be prevented ... [or wouldn't]
>
> It is reckoned that China can't be prevented ... [or couldn't]

or if there's some doubt in the reckoning:

> ... that China may not be prevented ...
>
> ... that China might not be prevented ...